# What benefits do using log returns for model training provide?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, machine-learning, log-returns

I came across a paper that uses Support Vector Machines to classify a `buy/sell/hold` decision each hour at the $\pm$0.5% threshold. The paper can bee seen [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.11819). The paper yielded impressive predictive power as well as high returns. It was noted that during the training phase they created the `[1, 0, -1]` labels by computing the percentage rate of change on log hourly returns.

I have looked at answers provided here [Why should we use log returns? Log normality](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/43158/why-should-we-use-log-returns-log-normality), however this wasn't in the context of label creation for an ML classification problem.

I was wondering if this technique offers predictive insight that using normal percentage returns? And if so, why does this work?

Comment: Just idea, maybe the feature $\frac{x-y}{y} \approx \ln(\frac{x}{y}) = \ln{x}-\ln{y}$ for $x$ close to $y$ can make something more simply?

Comment: But what benefit would that yield over using just returns without the log?

Comment: Sorry, I do not have time to go through whole article but I know that using a logarithm of some value can make other calculations more simple. Moreover, logarithm transform multiplication to addition which has lower computational cost..But as I said, just ideas.